# VBA script for checkbox not working

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

I have a problem in Excel 2013. Yesterday I put the following code in Excel by rightclicking the tab of my worksheet (Alt-F11) :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D3:T42")) Is Nothing Then
Application.EnableEvents = False
If Target.Value = ChrW(&H2713) Then
    Target.ClearContents
    Cancel = True
Else
    Target.Value = ChrW(&H2713)
    Cancel = True
End If
End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

This code is supposed to add a checkmark in the defined cells after double clicking. While this code worked fine yesterday, it now does not work anymore. I have tried everything but just do not get it to work. Any ideas ?

PS I would like to use such a code since a sheet with many form checkboxes makes it very slow (at least in my case)

Regards, Arno

Comment: Adding the error handling and the problem disappeared. It seems like it also had to do with Excel getting into designermodus as soon as I removed one of the form checkboxes. No I am not exactly sure what did it, but most important is that it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Some error in one test may have made `EnableEvents` keep false eternally.

Run a single sub with `Application.EnableEvents = true` and test it again.

If that is false, no event will be thrown at all, no clicks, no double clicks, nothing will work.

I suggest you add an `On error goto` statement, to avoid that kind of problem:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    On Error goto 1
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D3:T42")) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        If Target.Value = ChrW(&H2713) Then
            Target.ClearContents
            Cancel = True
        Else
            Target.Value = ChrW(&H2713)
            Cancel = True
        End If
    End If

    on error goto 0
1   Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```